# Recorrer objeto SDT colección y hacer un New en una tabla

Tags: java, genexus

Hola foro buenas tardes (o buenas noches).
Necesitaría saber como puedo enviar por parámetro un Variable basada en un una colección (SDT) por parámetros a un procedimiento; desde un Web Panel. Y, hacer un New en una tabla. El WBP recibe a partir de dos datos que se envían a un Web Services un Json con la respuesta. El SDT de tipo colección tiene los mismos datos del Json (nombres y tipo de datos).
Cualquier tips o ayuda me sirven.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar tu variable SDT por parámetros a un procedimiento, solo tienes que definir en el mismo una variable basada en el SDT, luego en las **rules** del procedimiento:

```
Parm(in:&VariableSDT);
```

Luego, desde el web panel, llamas al procedimiento pasándole como parámetro el SDT que tienes definido en el web panel:

```
Procedimiento.Call(&VariableSDT)
```

Para hacer un new en el procedimiento con el SDT, debes definir también una variable basada en el item del SDT, supongamos &VariableSDTItem y en el **source** recorrer el mismo para ir dando de alta los registros:

```
For &VariableSDTItem in &VariableSDT
    New
      Att1 = &VariableSDTItem.Valor1
      Att2 = &VariableSDTItem.Valor2
      ...
      AttN = &VariableSDTItem.ValorN
    EndNew
EndFor
```